# Can socket.io have a different URL for different users such as clients and admins

Tags: websocket, socket.io, localhost

I am building a socket.io site which would be used by teachers and students. The teacher will press a button on his side of the website in a classroom which would then redirect the student on his device to another page.

I have managed to get this working, however both the student and the teacher need to be connected to the same URL for it to work which is localhost:3000.

So my question is: can I have the site so the teacher uses a different URL to the student? This is because the teachers side will have different content to the students side which the students should not be able to see; hence the need for a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter the page the client is browsing, websockets will work either way as long as it has been defined in JavaScript.

For example:

You can make a **/teacher** page, where the teacher will input a URL and have a submit button. Then just add this code in your *app.js* after the button has been clicked:

```
var url = "Get link from the input field";
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
socket.emit('redirect', {link: url}); 
 });
```

And then make a **/student** page. Inside the student page, make sure to have the following javascript:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('redirect', function (data){
window.location = data.link; });
```

If the student will be browsing **/student**, it will redirect it to the url you have enetered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "need" a different URL.  You can just check the login cookie or session when they connect and see whether they are logged in as a student or teacher and then behave appropriately.  If you aren't using authentication to direct them to student or teacher content, then your site is not secure anyway.

If you want to segment a single socket.io into multiple different content streams, you can use socket.io's namespace feature.  The students would connect to the student namespace and the teachers would connect to the teacher namespace.  You will still need a secure way to know whether a teacher is actually a teacher or not.

You can read about namespaces on socket.io here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#namespace